# Attempting to load CSV to JSON format. Only seem to be getting last line specified of CSV in JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to write a python script to grab data from a CSV and format it into JSON in a specific nested format. I only seem to be getting the last line specified of the CSV. Please find my code below:

```
import csv, json, itertools
from collections import defaultdict
csvFilePath = "example.csv"
jsonFilePath = "example.json"
startCSV= 1
finishCSV= 10

# Read the CSV and add data to a dictionary
data = defaultdict()
with open(csvFilePath) as csvFile:
        tmp = {}
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
        for csvRow in itertools.islice(csv.DictReader(csvFile), begin, end):
            tmp['email'] = csvRow['email']
            del csvRow['email']
            tmp['dataFields'] = csvRow
            data.update(tmp)
            tmp = {}

#Write the data to a JSON file  
with open(jsonFilePath, "w") as jsonFile:
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

This looks to an issue in my loop where the data is getting overridden, but after hours of research, I am unsure how to resolve. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're copying the reference to the object from `csvRow` to `tmp` and then deleting the object to which they are both pointing.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're only getting the last line is because `csvRow` is iterating through to the last line in your csv file, and then adding itself to `data`.

To fix this, simply indent your loop body as follows:

```
with open(csvFilePath) as csvFile:
        tmp = {}
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
        for csvRow in itertools.islice(csv.DictReader(csvFile), startCSV, finishCSV):
            tmp['email'] = csvRow['email']
            del csvRow['email']
            tmp['dataFields'] = csvRow
            data.update(tmp)
            tmp = {}
```

Besides that, make sure that emails are unique in the csv file. According to the `dictionary.update()` [documentation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/update), a repeated email address will replace data in `data`. To fix this, replace `update()` with an `append()` call, and make `data` an array as stated in Brennen's solution.

```
with open(csvFilePath) as csvFile:
    # with `data = []`
    tmp = {}
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow in itertools.islice(csv.DictReader(csvFile), startCSV, finishCSV):
        tmp['email'] = csvRow['email']
        del csvRow['email']
        tmp['dataFields'] = csvRow
        data.append(tmp)          # CHANGED: You used update here.
        tmp = {}
```

Edit: If your email addresses in the csv aren't unique, then using them as keys (as stated in Brennan's *Minimal Solution with Email as the Key*) will still overwrite existing data.

Answer (score 2):

`update` updates keys and only appends if you provide new keys. Your `tmp` dict that you are using has the same keys in it. So each time you are calling `update` you are overwriting the old keys. You need to use arrays with `append` or set new keys for every data entry. I've provided a couple examples below.

### Test CSV

```
email,column_2_title,column_3_title
test@test.com,12,13
example@example.com,22,23
google.@google.com,32,33
```

### Minimal changes using array and append

```
import csv, json, itertools
from collections import defaultdict
csvFilePath = "example.csv"
jsonFilePath = "example.json"
startCSV= 0
finishCSV= 10

# Read the CSV and add data to a dictionary
data = []                         # CHANGED: You had data being a dict.
with open(csvFilePath) as csvFile:
    tmp = {}
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow in itertools.islice(csv.DictReader(csvFile), startCSV, finishCSV):
        tmp['email'] = csvRow['email']
        del csvRow['email']
        tmp['dataFields'] = csvRow
        data.append(tmp)          # CHANGED: You used update here.
        tmp = {}

#Write the data to a JSON file  
with open(jsonFilePath, "w") as jsonFile:
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

#### Output

```
[
    {
        "email": "test@test.com", 
        "dataFields": {
            "column_3_title": "13", 
            "column_2_title": "12"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "email": "example@example.com", 
        "dataFields": {
            "column_3_title": "23", 
            "column_2_title": "22"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "email": "google.@google.com", 
        "dataFields": {
            "column_3_title": "33", 
            "column_2_title": "32"
        }
    }
]
```

### Minimal changes using email as key

```
import csv, json, itertools
from collections import defaultdict
csvFilePath = "example.csv"
jsonFilePath = "example.json"
startCSV= 0
finishCSV= 10

# Read the CSV and add data to a dictionary
data = {}
with open(csvFilePath) as csvFile:
    tmp = {}
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow in itertools.islice(csv.DictReader(csvFile), startCSV, finishCSV):
        email = csvRow['email']    # CHANGED: Store just the email, we will use it as a key.
        del csvRow['email']
        tmp['dataFields'] = csvRow
        data[email] = tmp          # CHANGED: Set the `tmp` dict as the value with the key being the email.
        tmp = {}

#Write the data to a JSON file  
with open(jsonFilePath, "w") as jsonFile:
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

#### Output

```
{
    "google.@google.com": {
        "dataFields": {
            "column_3_title": "33", 
            "column_2_title": "32"
        }
    }, 
    "test@test.com": {
        "dataFields": {
            "column_3_title": "13", 
            "column_2_title": "12"
        }
    }, 
    "example@example.com": {
        "dataFields": {
            "column_3_title": "23", 
            "column_2_title": "22"
        }
    }
}
```